# PHP string comparison to a txt

Tags: php

The `$search` is a string of variables made from text inputs in a form. I am looking to see if that string is found in a txt file. I think something is wrong with my regex but I am not sure.

An existing entry to the text file would look like this `Title%Author%ISBN%Publisher%Year`.

My issue is that when I submit the form it goes to a blank page.

```
    elseif ($inquiry=='search') {

        $file= fopen("database.txt", "r") or die("File was not found on server"); 

        $search =  "/^[$Title."%".$Author."%".$ISBN."%".$Publisher."%".$Year]/i";

        //search function
        // What to look for

        // open and Read from file
        $lines = file('database.txt');//array

        foreach($lines as $line) {
            // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
            if(preg_match($search, $line)) {
                echo $line;
            } else {
                echo "Search not found";
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: the $lines is an array using foreach to traverse line by line

Comment: save yourself! parse the file into a database

Comment: You are likely getting a blank page bcs your `$search` specification line is not valid PHP - the `%` are unquoted and not appended to the rest of the string.  Your PHP and web server logs will tell you this - you are working blind if you're not using your logs.  Are the `%` literal, I mean do the lines in the txt file include actual percentage signs?

Comment: yes they do include % between the variables. How would i validate the regex? I also do not have access to logs. I am working on a remote server that i do not own

Comment: Validating the regex and getting your current problem fixed are 2 separate problems.  If you search for "validate regex" there are several online tools that help you build and test a regex against sample text, live.  As to fixing your syntax error, try something like this: `$search =  "/^[" . $Title . "%" . $Author . "%" . $ISBN . "%" . $Publisher . "%" . $Year . "]/i";`. Eyeballing it, I think you need to remove the `[]` - that indicates a character class, but you're looking for a literal match.

Comment: (I am assuming `$Title` and the other variables in your string are already defined, from your form, as you describe).  And check your logs! :-)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be aware of two things first.

The special `$` char in PHP is used to denominate a variable.

When you inject a word with a preceding `$` in a double quoted string, this is treated as a variable name and the variable tries to expand itself.

I'm mentioning this because of this line:

```
$search =  "/^[$Title."%".$Author."%".$ISBN."%".$Publisher."%".$Year]/i";
```

So, my best guess there is that you are trying to use and expand the variable names. So, if that's the case you are ok on your intention.

But be aware you have a missmatched and no closed " after the Title.

Also remember the `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, and they are usually used to try to match the "end of the line".

Note: Your script is probably dying due to a missing " after the Title.